# Find dy/dx of Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

really stuck on this problem, my textbook doesn't have ANYTHING like it.

The only instruction is to find the dy/dx of the interval:
$$y=x\int_2^{x^2}\sin(t^3)\,\mathrm dt $$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format problems into your question so you don't have to link to outside images. Putting the problem inside your question makes it just a bit easier for everyone else. Thanks!

Comment: If we define $f(x)=\int_a^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt$ for some continuous $g$, do you know a theorem that tells you what  $f'(x)$ is? Once you have that, what is the derivative of $x\mapsto xf(x^2)$? Saying your textbook has NOTHING like this is saying that you didn't cover the fundamental theorem of integration/differentiation, not the chain rule, and not the product rule for differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem tricky at first but by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$F(b)-F(a)=\int^b_a f(x)~\mathrm dx$$
and by the Second Fundamental Theorem of calculus
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)~dt \Rightarrow F'(x)=f(x).$$
So, in this case, all you are really doing is taking the derivative of the right-hand side.
$$y(x)=x\int_2^{x^2}\sin(t^3)~\mathrm dt$$
$$y'(x)=\int_2^{x^2}\sin(t^3)~\mathrm dt+x\cdot(2 x \sin(x^6))$$ 
and I'll let you do the rest.

Comment: thanks! this was really helpful. by the rest do you mean just evaluate the integral part of it too? Just not entirely sure what the 'rest' is

Comment: Yes, he/she means for you to evaluate the integral. After that, you should have your answer.